# What code would I use to put parentheses around all the occurrences of a term/substring?

Tags: java, string, methods, header, parentheses

I know how to do it... but the way I'm thinking is complicated and has a lot of room for errors. I'm still learning Java, but I have learned that Java has ways of doing just about anything. Is there some way I can put parentheses around each occurrence of a substring? (see an example below)

Original String: "abcabcabcd"

Search For: "abc"

Final Output: "(abc)(abc)(abc)d"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with `String#replace`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way here is to use [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
String str = "abcabcabcd";
String sub = "abc";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(sub, "(" + sub + ")"));
```

As pointed out by @Jacob G., [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) may be preferred here because there is no regex element needed.

**Output:**

> (abc)(abc)(abc)d

Comment: I recommend `String#replace` over `String#replaceAll` since you're not working with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in another solution, there is one with recursion. Just for educational purpose:

```
private static String parentheses(String input, String template) {
    int start = input.indexOf(template);

    if (start == -1) {
        return input;
    }

    return input.substring(0, start) +
            "(" + input.substring(start, start + template.length()) + ")" +
            parentheses(input.substring(start + template.length()), template);
}
```